# pycharm path difference for console and terminal

Tags: python, path, pycharm

So this is my project structure:

```
project folder
├───data
│   └───external
│        └───data.csv
└───src
    └───data
         └───make_data.py
```

If I run this in in pycharm with "run", so in terminal there is no problem. I like working interactively with the python console in pycharm, but then the path cannot be found as it is executed in the working directory "project folder". Consequently, when I remove the part "../.." it also works in the python console. I have marked src folder and the subfolders as sources root and the data folder and subfolder as resource root. In the settings of the python console in pycharm I have ticked both "Add contents/source roots to PYTHONPATH".

```
import os.path
import pandas as pd

fileDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath('__file__'))
filename = os.path.join(fileDir, '../../data/external/data.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
```

How can I achieve that it works one way in the console and the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

@Peterhack,

Working with paths across different python environments can be tricky on the same machine and even worse on different OSs (e.g. windows). Your first lines use the python path abstractions, so let's continue with that direction for locating your data directory. Here is a little bit verbose example for clarity:

```
import os.path
import pandas as pd

fileDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath('__file__'))
print(fileDir)
# /Users/starver/code/makara/stackoverflow/python/46912753/src/data

rootDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(fileDir))
print(rootDir)
# /Users/starver/code/makara/stackoverflow/python/46912753

dataDir = os.path.join(rootDir, 'data', 'external')
print(dataDir)
#/Users/starver/code/makara/stackoverflow/python/46912753/data/external

dataFile = os.path.join(dataDir, 'data.csv')
print(dataFile)
# /Users/starver/code/makara/stackoverflow/python/46912753/data/external/data.csv

df = pd.read_csv(dataFile)
```